# Как в набор ComboBox добавить null объект?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть комбо бокс

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding ***}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, TargetNullValue='Не выбрано'}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Наполняется он из источника

```
public List<SomeClass> SomeList
{
    get
    {
        var res = new List<SomeClass>
        {
            null
        };

        if (_someList!=null)
            res.AddRange(_someList);
        return res;
    }
    set
    {
        _someList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SomeList));
    }
}
```

То есть в сначала создается лист с единственным значением Null, затем уже в него добавляется лист с целевым набором. На форме первый элемент должен иметь подпись "Не выбрано", но на деле там просто пустая строка. Что не так в этом коде?

**UPD:**

Из описания BindingBase.TargetNullValue понятно, что оно для тех случаев, когда свойство объекта равно null, но в моем случае null равен сам объект. И мне именно это и нужно, чтобы объект был пустым, а не просто его свойство. Что тогда делать?

**UPD2:**

Помогло следующее. Добавил в `SomeClass` переопределенный метод `ToString()` который возвращает свойство `Name`, а биндинг в текстбоксе заменил на

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TargetNullValue='Не выбрано'}"/>
```

Такое работает, но мне не нравится. Не всегда мне нужно будет выводить именно Name, а делать для каждого такого случая новую вью модель - не вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел решение. Вообще, думаю, есть и более красивое и короткое решение.

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Не выбрано"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Resources>
</TextBlock>
```

**UPD:**

Нашел более правильное, на мой взгляд, решение. Причина - в коллекции не должно быть элемента null, иначе форма начинает работать неадекватно.

В класс `SomeClass` добавил статичное свойство `Empty`, возвращающее экземпляр этого же класса со значениями свойств, соответствующими пустому объекту. В моем случае это `Id = -1 , Name = null` , подобно как в стринге.

```
public static SomeClass Empty { get; } = new SomeClass { Id = -1, Name = null };
```

После этого вполне можно в xaml писать так

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, TargetNullValue='Не выбрано'}"/>
```

и к тому же `SomeClass.Empty == SomeClass.Empty`